# Ability to suggest tag synonyms without 5 in the tag

Tags: feature-request

There are some little used tags that have synonyms. It is hard to get 5 reputation in these tags (they are little used!) but synonyms could still be useful. Indeed, they might be especially useful as ways to combine tiny tags.

Can the system be modified so that people can add tag synonyms without 5 reputation in the tag itself?

Comment: I have a strong sense that I know what you're getting at here, but *technically* this isn't a question. Would you care to edit / clarify?

Comment: I didn't know feature requests had to be questions. :-) I've changed it

Comment: They don't, always, but sometimes doing so helps clarify what one is asking for. :)